# Hierarchies in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Im working my way though an ASP.NET MVC tutorial and couldnt find the answer im looking for.

I understand that each controller class in the 'Controller' root folder is mapped to a Url, so:

```
****Controller Folder****
    |- StoreController.cs
```

Maps to `$url/Store`

However, If I wish to creater a 'subfolder'

I.e. a Controller class located for `$url/Store/Testing` I cant seem to see how I go about it.
I tried deriving a class from `StoreController.cs`, but that didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLs do not necessarily correspond to MVC application internal folder structure. You can use MVC routing tables to conceal the internal structure and redirect specific URLs to any controllers/actions you want. For example, you can create a `TestingController.cs` class in the `Controllers` folder and use this route in `Global.asax`:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Store-Testing", // Route name
            "Store/Testing/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Testing", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

In this case, a request to `http://[domain]/Store/Testing` will be handled by TestingController.

Answer (score 0):

That url would with the default route point to an action called Testing, within the Store controller.

You can however create your own custom routes in your global.asax file.